# Can my MacBook use F2-5300CL5S RAM from my HP laptop?

Tags: hardware, memory

I have a MacBook with PC2-5300S memory in it. I have an HP laptop with F2-5300CL5S in it. I'd like to take my 2GB modules from my HP and move them into the MacBook. Are these memory modules compatible? Can anything go wrong from using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently they are compatible. I just tried it and the machine is zipping along now. It seems that the difference between the modules is latency and caching, which are close enough that the RAM will still work just fine.